# uml aggregation in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, uml

I've Intellij IDEA 2016.1.1. 
Why does Intellij UML diagram always draw composition line instead aggregation?

My code:

```
public class Address {

    int streetNum;
    String city;
    String state;
    String country;

    Address(int street, String c, String st, String coun)
    {
        this.streetNum=street;
        this.city =c;
        this.state = st;
        this.country = coun;
    }

}

public class StudentClass {

    int rollNum;
    String studentName;
    Address studentAddr;

    StudentClass(int roll, String name, Address addr){
        this.rollNum=roll;
        this.studentName=name;
        this.studentAddr = addr;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Address ad = new Address(55, "Agra", "UP", "India");
        StudentClass obj = new StudentClass(123, "Chaitanya", ad);
        System.out.println(obj.rollNum);
        System.out.println(obj.studentName);
        System.out.println(obj.studentAddr.streetNum);
        System.out.println(obj.studentAddr.city);
        System.out.println(obj.studentAddr.state);
        System.out.println(obj.studentAddr.country);
    }

}
```

You can see, that line is described Composition?
Why?

Intellij draw:

[image]

Comment: I'm not very familiar with intellij, but your Student Class contains the main method where the objects are instantiated. If you were to create a separate class for the main method, it shouldn't show as composition anymore.

Comment: Because the Student Class owns the life cycle of the Address object. I think it's a bit confusing since you have your static void main method in your Student Class. If you were to take your main method and put it in a completely separate class, it would be Aggregation/Association because the Student Object would not own the life of the Address object. https://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/association-vs-dependency-vs-aggregation-vs-composition/

Comment: ok. i'v done/ look at this please

Comment: How can I add the image here?

Comment: Even worse: it's a 1..1 aggregation (WTF?) and it's stereotyped `<<create>>`.

Comment: I don't no, this is IntelliJ IDEA )))

Comment: I'm afraid there might be two overlapping relationships on this diagram. One is the composite aggregation (coming from the fact you've got an attribute of class Address within Student) and the second one is a Create relationship to indicate that Student object initiates Address object.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram generator has no idea if the Address object is reusable across different Student objects (and thus this is Association OR Shared Aggregation) or rather each Student object has it's own unique Address object (resulting in Composite Aggregation). To recognize that the generator would have to analyse the behaviour and it still might not give a definite answer.

On the other hand when the diagram generator analyses class structure (and that's probably the only thing it is doing) it just recognises that object of class Student is build of object of class Address - which means this is a whole-part relationship (i.e. Composite Aggregation). And that's how it drew your diagram.

Now some diagram in such case model the relationship as (navigable) Association while some Composite Aggregation. Neither approach is 100% right but automated mechanism will never be able to understand such fuzzy logic.

Apparently Intellij uses the latter approach. That's all.